# Having an issue with formatting a String input

Tags: java, string, joptionpane, filewriter, printwriter

I'm trying to get the input that the user enters to go to lower-case and then put the first character in the input to upper-case. For example, If I enter aRseNAL for my first input, I want to format the input so that it will put "Arsenal" into the data.txt file, I'm also wondering if there's a way to put each first character to upper-case if there's more than one word for a team ie. mAN uNiTeD formatted to Man United to be written to the file.

The code I have below is what i tried and I cannot get it to work. Any advice or help would be appreciated.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class write
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        FileWriter aFileWriter = new FileWriter("data.txt");
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(aFileWriter);
        String team = "";
        for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            boolean isTeam = true;
            while(isTeam)
            {
                team = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a team: ");
                if(team == null || team.equals(""))
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a team.");
                else
                    isTeam = false;
            }
            team.toLowerCase();                 //Put everything to lower-case.
            team.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();  //Put the first character to upper-case.
            out.println(i + "," + team);
        }
        out.close();
        aFileWriter.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, strings are immutable (cannot be changed) so methods like `substring` and `toLowerCase` generate new strings - they don't modify your existing string.

So rather than:

```
team.toLowerCase();                
team.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();  
out.println(team);
```

You'd need something like:

```
String first = team.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();  
String rest = team.substring(1,team.length()).toLowerCase();                
out.println(first + rest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar as @DNA suggested but that will throw Exception if String length is 1. So added a check for same.

```
        String output = team.substring(0,1).toUpperCase(); 
        // if team length is >1 then only put 2nd part
        if (team.length()>1) {
            output = output+ team.substring(1,team.length()).toLowerCase();
        }
        out.println(i + "," + output);
```